# Error: unexpected symbol when looking for median and mean

Tags: r

I get this error while trying to get the median and mean of the data. I can't figure out the mistake.

> Error: unexpected symbol in "  geom_vline(data = gap (aes(xintercept =
> median(infant_mortality))col"

This is the full code I'm using.

```
gap %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = infant_mortality, col = region)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 10) + 
  geom_vline(data = gap (aes(xintercept = mean(infant_mortality))col = "#92d6d5") +
  geom_vline(data = gap (aes(xintercept = median(infant_mortality))col = "#a4c27f")
```

Nothing I've tried has worked, but I'm not really sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a comma before `col` and after `gap`, this will probably work:

```
gap %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = infant_mortality, col = region)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 10) + 
  geom_vline(data = gap, aes(xintercept = mean(infant_mortality)),col = "#92d6d5") +
  geom_vline(data = gap, aes(xintercept = median(infant_mortality)),col = "#a4c27f")
```

Comment: Thank you, this made it so I don't get the error message but the mean and median lines don't show up any more. it does give me a warning message Warning messages:
1: Removed 1453 rows containing non-finite values (stat_bin). 
2: Removed 10545 rows containing missing values (geom_vline). 
3: Removed 10545 rows containing missing values (geom_vline)

Comment: That is because there are missing values in infant_mortality

Comment: I completely overlooked that, thank you.